# Handling a timeout in EJB3 without using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, ejb-3.0

I have the following situation. I have a job that:

- May time out after a given amount of time, and if so occurs needs to throw an exception
- If it does not time out, will return a result
- If this job returns a result, it must be returned as quickly as possible, because performance is very much an issue. Asynchronous solutions are hence off the table, and naturally tying up the system by hammering isn't an option either.
- Lastly, the system has to conform to the EJB standard, so AFAIK using ordinary threads is not an option, as this is strictly forbidden.

Our current solution uses a thread that will throw an exception after having existed for a certain amount of time without being interrupted by an external process, but as this clearly breaks the EJB standard, we're trying to solve it with some other means.

Any ideas?

**Edited to add:** Naturally, a job which has timed out needs to be removed (or interrupted) as well.

**Edited to add 2:**
This issue doesn't seem to have any solution, because detecting a deadlock seems to be mostly impossible sticking to pure EJB3 standards. Since Enno Shioji's comments below reflect this, I'm setting his suggestion as the correct answer.

Comment: Which application server are you using? Most JEE app servers allows you (although implementation specific) to define a timeout on EJB business methods.

Comment: @jarnbjo: We have to be AS agnostic, so we can't use any AS specific functions.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Executors are based on threads, are they not? If so, use of them is also prohibited by the EJB standard.

Comment: @mikek, the spec might explicitly allow some use of executors if the container manages the threads.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I'm not sure...perhaps a new SO question? ^_^

Comment: @mikek: I think EJB 3.1 brought lightweight asynchronous processing into the spec (It's an EJB provided service). As for using "raw" threads inside AS, actually it works ok unless you mess with container provided services with the "illicit" thread. The argument by the AS dev. ppl is that making bunch of illicit threads messes up the performance consideration of the AS. I have in fact tried using a background thread with JBoss before. Though we removed that quite soon because we didn't want to do something that isn't allowed on paper at least...

Comment: @Enno Shioji: We're looking to have our application certified, so sticking to the EJB standard is important to us in this case.

Comment: @Enno Shioji: agreed, EJB 3.1 @Asynchronous with Future.get(timeout) and Future.cancel(true), which notifies SessionContext.wasCancelCalled, seem like a perfect fit for this.  @mikek: did you intend to exclude EJB 3.1 with the ejb-3.0 tag?

Comment: @bkail: Sadly yes, I'm stuck with using EJB3.0 at the moment. EJB3.1 isn't as far as I know widely supported yet, is it?

Comment: @mikek: I updated my answer with 2 suggestions, but have to say neither are very good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a request for clarification, but it's too long to fit as a comment..

I'm not sure how you are doing it right now, since from what you wrote, just using the request processing thread seems to be the way to go. Like this:

```
//Some webservice method (synchronous)
public Result process(Blah blah){
    try{
        return getResult(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 10);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        //No result within 10 seconds!
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException("blah");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you are creating threads at all. If you are forced to use threads because the `getResult` method doesn't timeout at all, you would have a thread leak. If it timeouts after a longer time and thus you want to "shortcut" your reply to the user, that would be the only case I'd consider using a thread like I imagine how you are using it. This could result in Threads piling up under load and I'd strive to avoid such situation.

Maybe you can post some code and let us know why you are creating in your service at all?

Also, what's your client interface? Sounds like it's a synchronous webservice or something?

---

In that case, if I were you I would use a `HashedWheelTimer` as a singleton... this mechanism should work great with your requirement ([here is an implementation](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/util/HashedWheelTimer.html)). However, this unfortunately seem to conflict with the ban on threading AND the ban on singleton in the EJB spec. In reality though there really isn't a problem if you would do this. See [this discussion](http://www.oreillynet.com/cs/user/view/cs_msg/17107) for example. We have also used the singleton pattern in our EJB app. which used JBoss. However, if this isn't a viable choice then I might look at isolating the processing in its own JVM by defining a new web service (and deploy it in a web-container or something), and call that service from the EJB app. This would however obviously incur performance hit and now you would have another whole new app.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same level here, but my code needs to detect the timeout on its own. Hence I need to start a thread to poll if the process has produced a result after the timeout period. Is that clearer?

Comment: @mikek: I guess my point is, if your original thread is doing the task itself, it could check for timeout by it self, right? Even if it calls external blocking methods, most of the time a timeout can be specified for such methods. Like locking a lock, making a network request... usually you can specify a timeout. So if that's the case, I thought you might be better off by just using these facilities. If your original thread does something that never timeouts, *then* you would indeed need a thread that interrupts that original thread after timeout. But AFAIK such methods are rather rare.

Comment: The latter situation is exactly what we have.

Answer (score 1):

With Bean Managed Transaction, the timeout for the specific transaction can be specified by using  UserTransaction interface.

> Modify the timeout value that is
>   associated with transactions started
>   by the current thread with the begin
>   method.

```
void setTransactionTimeout(int seconds) throws SystemException
```

- Transaction will timeout after specified seconds & may not get propagated further. If exception is not thrown implicitly, then can throw it explicitly based on the result.
- Will return a result on successful completion within specified time.
- Can use it with stateless session beans so there may not be a performance issue.
- Its EJB standard so that will not be an issue to implement.

With little-bit work around, it should work fine in the given scenario.

**Edit :** Also can use server specific properties to manage transaction timeout.

*JBoss* : At either at class or method level annotation `@TransactionTimeout(100)` can be applied.

*Weblogic* : Specifying the parameters in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

```
<transaction-descriptor>
     <trans-timeout-seconds>100</trans-timeout-seconds> 
</transaction-descriptor>
```

*GlassFish* : Using the optional `cmt-timeout-in-seconds` element in sun-ejb-jar.xml

Comment: We need to be application server agnostic as far as possible, so this is not the preferred solution. AFAIK method level timouts can't be specified on Glassfish, for example.

Comment: UserTransaction interface isn't server specific. I have provided server specific solution as an alternative, edited to include glassfish support.

Comment: No go. Even though BMTs are nicely AS agnostic, the timeout is only thrown if and when the transaction actually commits. If a dead-lock occurs within the transaction, it'll never time out. I'm not entirely sure, but I believe that this is according to the EJB spec.

Comment: @mikek As you are managing transactions manually, can commit it when your processing is done, so as you are saying exception will rise then. And for deadlocks, have to manage transaction propagation carefully.

Comment: Still not. I have a situation where a hardware interface may deadlock indefinitely, and no transaction timeout will AFAIK and as far as my experimenting shows ever figure this fact out.

Answer (score 1):

Stick the process and it's timeout thread in to a class annotated with @WebService, put that class in to a WAR, then invoke the WebService from your EJB.

WARs don't have the same limitations or live under the same contract that EJBs do, so they can safely run threads.

Yes, I consider this a "hack", but it meets the letter of the requirements, and it's portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create threads using the commonj WorkManager.  There are implementations built into [WebSphere](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/beta/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/asyncbns/concepts/casb_workmgr.html) and [Weblogic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/self_tuned.html) as they proposed the standard, but you can also find implementations for other appservers as well.

Basically, the WorkManager allows you to create managed threads inside the container, much like using an Executor in regular Java.  Your only other alternative would be to use MDB's, but that would be a 'heavier' solution.

Since I don't know your actual platform, you will have to google commonj with your platform yourself 8-)

Here is a [non IBM or Oracle solution.](http://commonj.myfoo.de/)

**Note:** This is not an actual standard, but it is widely available for different platforms and should suit your purposes nicely.

Answer (score 0):

For EJBs, there is a concept of "Container Managed Transactions".  By specifying @TransactionAttribute on your bean, or specific method, the container will create a transaction when ever the method(s) are invoked. If the execution of the code takes longer than the transaction threshold, the container will throw an exception.  If the call finishes under the transaction threshold, it will return as usual.  You can catch the exception in your calling code and handle it appropriately.

For more on container managed transactions, check out: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Transaction3.html and http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html

Comment: The thought was nice, but there doesn't seem to be any AS agnostic standard for handling timeouts of CMTs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`@TimeOut`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/Timeout.html). Something like:

```
@Stateless
public class TimedBean {

  @Resource
  private TimerService timerService;

  static private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
  static private Map<Integer, AtomicBoolean> canIRunStore = new ...;

  public void doSomething() {
    Integer myId = counter.getAndIncrement();
    AtomicBoolean canIRun = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    canIRunStore.put(myId, canIRun);

    timerService.createTimer(1000, 0, myId);

    while (canIRun.get() /* && some other condition */) {
      // do my work ... untill timeout ... 
    }
  }

  @Timeout
  @PermitAll
  public void timeout(Timer timer) {
    Integer expiredId = (Integer) timer.getInfo();
    AtomicBoolean canHeRun = canIRunStore.get(expiredId);
    canIRunStore.remove(expiredId);
    canHeRun.set(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work very well if your server crashes because EJB timers are persistent.

Comment: EJB timers can be set to be one-shot, so that isn't the issue. The problem is that the part of my code that may dead-lock is a 3rd party library, of which I have no control, so no way of checking for expiration.