# Is there any way of interrupting a stateful session bean?

Tags: java, timeout, ejb-3.0, stateful-session-bean

This question is somewhat related to [Handling a timeout in EJB3 without using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142605/handling-a-timeout-in-ejb3-without-using-threads).

**Background**:
I have an example of an operation that may lock up while it's running, and I have to be able to handle that eventuality and kill the operation if so happens. The solution has to be application server agnostic, so container managed transactions with timout values are not an option.

**Actual Question**:
One idea for a solution that I had running the operation in a stateful session bean, and using an external @Timeout method to monitor it, but for this to work I need to be able to interrupt or cancel that session bean. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Why does application server independence rule out using container managed transactions? CMTs are part of the Java EE spec, which every Java EE application server must implement.

Comment: @Matt: Ah, I meant CMTs with timouts. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec says (§4.3.14):

> The container serializes calls to each
>   stateful and stateless session bean
>   instance. Most containers will support
>   many instances of a session bean
>   executing concurrently; however, each
>   instance sees only a serialized
>   sequence of method calls. Therefore, a
>   stateful or stateless session bean
>   does not have to be coded as
>   reentrant.

There is thus no way of calling a session bean instance's method while another method of the same instance is still running.

Comment: The same is true for Java in general.  You have to implement "cooperative interruption" by coding the interruptible task to periodically poll whether it has been interrupted.