# Make EJB call with timeout

Tags: jakarta-ee, timeout, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I have an EJB `A` that invokes EJB `B`. The UI should not wait for more than 30 seconds for a response. If some data is missing, it should return a partial response.

How can I define a timeout (time limit of 30 seconds) on EJB `B`?

I can define EJB `B` as `Asynchronous` that returns `Future`, and then do `Future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.
But is it the best solution?

thank you

P.S. I use glassfish 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure timeout for a bean which applies to all its methods, you have to configure the attribute `cmt-timeout-in-seconds` in glassfish-ejb-jar.xml.

This timeout value is used by all the methods of the bean that initiates a new transaction, not applicable when they join other ongoing transaction.

Also can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6144695) for further details on timeout.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using the transaction timeout for this.

I don't think there is a standard way of configuring it so it would depend on the application server. I assume you want to set it specifically per class or method.

For WebLogic you can specify it in "weblogic-ejb-jar.xml" in the "transaction-descriptor" or use the annotation "@TransactionTimeoutSeconds".

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13719/ejb_jar_ref.htm#i1506703

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13720/annotations.htm#i1438354

For JBoss AS you could set the transaction timeout using the annotation "@TransactionTimeout" or in "jboss.xml".

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout

I am sure there are similar configuration options in every application server.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to interrupt a target EJB.  The only real option is for the target EJB to cooperatively and periodically check whether it has exceeded the intended target response time.

Even if you use `@Asynchronous` and the `Future.get` times out, you've simply unblocked the client from waiting for the result; the target EJB will continue to execute and consume resources.  However, with asynchronous methods, you do have the benefit of some builtin cooperative cancellation using `Future.cancel` and `SessionContext.wasCancelCalled`.

Comment: I do not mean to interrupt EJB. The idea was to return response (or "timeout error") to UI after 30 seconds.

Comment: Sure, but timing out the front-end without timing out the back-end seems unwise.  Eventually, your back-end threads will be consumed and your front-end threads will have to wait anyway.  Given what you've said, using `@Asynchronous` is probably best.