# JavaEE - EJB/CDI Method Duration Mechanism

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

not sure how to title this issue but lets hope description may give better explaination. I am looking for a way to annotate a ejb method or cdi method with a custom annotation like " @Duration" or someothing aaand so to kill methods execution if takes too long after the given duration period. I guess some pseudo code will make everything clear:

```
public class myEJBorCdiBean {

@Duration(seconds = 5)
public List<Data> complexTask(..., ...)
{
  while(..)
  // this takes more time than the given 5 seconds so throw execption
}
```

To sum up, a method takes extremely long and it shall throw a given time duration expired error or something like that

Kinda a timeout mechanism, I dont know if there is already something like this, I am new to javaEE world.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: In [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916079/365237), transaction timeouts were proposed as a solution, and to me it would fit your use case perfectly. They are not standard but exist in pretty much all app servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to use Threading API inside EJB/CDI container. EJB spec clearly states that:

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise
>   bean must not attempt to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or
>   to change a thread’s priority or name. The enterprise bean must not
>   attempt to manage thread groups.

Managed beans and the invocation of their business methods have to be fully controlled by the container in order to avoid corruption of their state. Depending on your usecase, either offload this operation to a dedicated service(outside javaee), or you could come up with some semi-hacking solution using EJB `@Singleton` and `Schedule` - so that you could periodically check for some control flag. If you are running on Wildfly/JBoss, you could misuse the `@TransactionTimeout` annotation for this- as EJB methods are by default transaction aware, setting the timeout on Transaction will effective control the invocation timeout on the bean method. I am not sure, how it is supported on other applications servers.

If async processing is an option, then EJB `@Asynchronous` could be of some help: see [Asynchronous tutorial - Cancelling and asynchronous operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html).

As a general advice: Do not run long running ops in EJB/CDI. Every request will spawn a new thread, threads are limited resource and your app will be much harder to scale and maintain(long running op ~= state), what happens if your server crashes during method invocation, how would the use case work in clustered environment. Again it is hard to say, what is a better approach without understanding of your use case, but investigate java EE batch api, JMS with message driven beans or asynchronous processing with `@Asynchronous`

Comment: how come there is no such solution by design in ejb javaee world? I mean I am not the first one who wants to set duration on method? it must be solved with a thread kinda thing... Do you have a solution in code for me?

Comment: It is an architectural decision, because server/container manages the component state, invocations, chaining, transactions, interceptors,contexts... EJB and CDI spec define rules and features for server managed beans-that is why you cant use Threading api. You still did not mention your use case, but I guess you are mixing timeout handling on the client and on the server. What exactly do you expect to happen, when you terminate your method? - is it an error, is it an OK state, what should happen to the resources involved. Any code that would handle it without @Asynchronous would be a hack.

Comment: I mean how come there is no such thing like throw exception after duration > 5 seconds... it is useful feature. Error shall happen instead of waiting for minutes to finish

Answer (score 0):

It is a very meaningful idea – to limit a complex task to a certain execution time. In practical web-computing, many users will be unwilling to wait for a complex search task to complete when its duration exceeds a maximally acceptable amount of time.

The Enterprise container controls the thread pool, and the allocation of CPU-resources among the active threads. It does so taking into account also retention times during time-consuming I/O-tasks (typically disk access).

Nevertheless, it makes sense to program a start task variable, and so now and then during the complex task verify the duration of that particular task. I advice you to program a local, runnable task, which picks scheduled tasks from a job queue. I have experience with this from a Java Enterprise backend application running under Glassfish.

First the interface definition **Duration.java**

```
// Duration.java 
@Qualifier 
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
public @interface Duration {
    public int minutes() default 0; // Default, extended from class, within path 
}
```

Now follows the definition of the job **TimelyJob.java**

```
// TimelyJob.java    
@Duration(minutes = 5)
public class TimelyJob {

    private LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    private UUID uniqueTaskIdentifier;
    private String uniqueOwnerId;

    public TimelyJob(UUID uniqueTaskIdentifier, String uniqueOwnerId) {
        this.uniqueTaskIdentifier = uniqueTaskIdentifier;
        this.uniqueOwnerId = uniqueOwnerId;
    }

    public void processUntilMins() {
        final int minutes = this.getClass().getAnnotation(Duration.class).minutes();
        while (true) {
            // do some heavy Java-task for a time unit, then pause, and check total time
            // break - when finished
            if (minutes > 0 && localDateTime.plusMinutes(minutes).isAfter(LocalDateTime.now())) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.print(e);
            }
        }
        // store result data in result class, 'synchronized'  access
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime() {
        return localDateTime;
    }

    public UUID getUniqueTaskIdentifier() {
        return uniqueTaskIdentifier;
    }

    public String getUniqueOwnerId() {
        return uniqueOwnerId;
    }        
}
```

The Runnable task that executes the timed jobs - **TimedTask.java** - is implemented as follows:

```
// TimedTask.java
public class TimedTask implements Runnable {

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<TimelyJob> jobQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<TimelyJob>();

    public void setJobQueue(TimelyJob job) {
        this.jobQueue.add(job);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                TimelyJob nextJob = jobQueue.take();
                nextJob.processUntilMins();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.print(e);
            }
         }
      } 
   }
```

and in a seperate code, the staring of the `TimedTask`

```
   public void initJobQueue() {
       new Thread(new TimedTask()).start();
   }
```

This functionality actually implements a batch-job scheduler in Java, using annotations to control the end-task time limit.